# Is there a more efficient way of building a query without unions and repeating statements?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that essentially finds all members and their families who are eligible for a specific product. Each family member is listed on an individual row, even if they belong to the same family. We use MySQL of note.

For example (a small sample of all data actually returned):

```
ID  | familyid |  firstname | lastname | address      | city      | relationship
==============================================================================
1   |    1     |   john     |  davis   | 942 James Ln | cityplace | primary
2   |    1     |   suzy     |  davis   | 942 James Ln | cityplace | spouse
3   |    2     |   andrew   |  smith   | 444 A Rd     | new york  | primary
4   |    3     |   Mike     |  lewis   | 123 Street   | dallas    | primary
5   |    3     |   Donna    |  lewis   | 123 Street   | dallas    | child
1   |    3     |   Jamie    |  lewis   | 123 Street   | dallas    | child
```

The (made up) data in the table above comes from two tables:

> 1. Primary Information (contains all general information about member and address)
> 2. Family Information (contains spouse and children's name and gender information)

For simplicity sake, let's assume the only information contained in these tables is as follows:

## member

```
ID | familyid | firstname | lastname | address | city
-----------------------------------------------------
```

## family

```
ID | familyid | firstname | lastname | type | gender
------------------------------------------------------
```

Members in our system can have several products they have selected (information house in a separate table). Unfortunately, the only way I know to build the statement like above is to select the same information twice essentially, then perform UNION ALL statement like the following sample statement:

```
SELECT r.* FROM (
  SELECT familyid, firstname, lastname, address, city, 'primary'
  FROM member
 UNION ALL
  SELECT a.familyid, b.firstname, b.lastname, a.address, a.city, IF(b.type = 1, 'spouse', 'child')
  FROM member a
  JOIN family b ON (a.familyid = b.familyid)
) r
```

This is already a bit of a mess but the 'real' issue comes when i start joining several other tables to the 'name' information already collected. For example, I could add a join statement to the overall query to only show members or families who have selected HBO television service:

```
after last statement: JOIN channels c ON (r.familyid = c.familyid)
```

This will weed out all members in the previously selected statement who do not have HBO, but what if I want to select sub-sections of HBO (such as, those who have the member only version versus the whole family version). These subsequent queries essentially force me to make the exact same call twice returning only slightly different information.

```
SELECT r.* FROM (
  SELECT familyid, firstname, lastname, address, city, 'primary'
  FROM member m
  JOIN channels c ON (m.familyid = c.familyid)
  WHERE c.name = "HBO" and c.memtype = "member only"
 UNION ALL
  SELECT a.familyid, b.firstname, b.lastname, a.address, a.city, IF(b.type = 1, 'spouse', 'child')
  FROM member a
  JOIN family b ON (a.familyid = b.familyid)
  JOIN channels c ON (b.familyid = c.familyid)
  WHERE c.name = "HBO" and c.memtype = "family"
) r
```

Is there a way to better optimize these statements? Is MySQL just SOL on this matter?

NOTE:
The tables are normalized as is so please don't suggest to improve them. This particular query is just for a single report generated once a month automatically and as needed (very infrequent). I am merely trying to find out if it is possible to avoid the Union statements with the schemas as they are. The schema cannot be modified.

Comment: So `family.type` can have only 2 values, either `1` or `0`?

Comment: @ypercube - for the time being yes but if I needed more I could just use a CASE statement.

Comment: Are you able to change the structure of the schema?

Comment: @njk - yes but not sure it makes sense to do that. A member can have 20+ dependents, just like the channels the primary member can have, these are dynamic and should not be contained in the primary table.

Comment: Not sure of the context, but the `relationship` isn't really normalized.

Comment: relationship is defined based on the combination of the two tables, it is only generated for a specific report. See the query. 'relationship' is not stored anywhere in my database.

Comment: Would you be open to trying a different schema?

Comment: @njk - after more thought, no, the schema cannot change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the `member` table to store the "primary" members of a family and the family address and using the `family` table to store the information about the rest people in a family. This seems not very well designed and the names not very well chosen.

Suggestion: Add all "primary" members to `family` table as well, with a new, third `type`:

```
INSERT INTO family
  (family_id, type, firstname, lastname)
SELECT family_id, 2, firstname, lastname
FROM member ;
```

Then you can use the simply join for the `r` query:

```
SELECT a.familyid, b.firstname, b.lastname, a.address, a.city, 
       CASE b.type 
         WHEN 0 THEN 'child'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'spouse'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'primary'
       END AS type
FROM member a
  JOIN family b 
    ON a.familyid = b.familyid ;
```

You might even drop the `firstname` and `lastname` columns from the `member` table (and perhaps rename the tables to reflect their usage better).

---

The second scenario would be written as:

```
SELECT a.familyid, b.firstname, b.lastname, a.address, a.city, 
       CASE b.type 
         WHEN 0 THEN 'child'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'spouse'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'primary'
       END AS type
FROM member a
  JOIN family b 
    ON a.familyid = b.familyid
  JOIN channels c 
    ON b.familyid = c.familyid
WHERE c.name = 'HBO' AND ( b.type <> 2 AND c.memtype = 'family'  
                        OR b.type  = 2 AND c.memtype = 'member only'
                         ) ;
```

Comment: 1) the names are samples, I'm not giving the actual names of my tables. 2) thank you for taking the time to respond but I don't see how your suggestion answers the overal question. The actual member table has a ton of real information. It is the most important table in our whole system. The 'family' table simply links any additional persons to that member and ultimately is absolutely no different than the new family table you describe.

Comment: I'm suggesting to transfer (copy the data from members to family and then remove these columns from members) for those columns that are in both tables (like `firstname` and `lastname`). This solves the problem because you don't have to `UNION` any more.

Comment: The union even if your new table would exist because of the example scenario given. Just because a member has a family does not mean his family has the "family" level product. Members can choose multiple products, some with member only status and others with family status.

Comment: I am curious why you say "this seems not very well designed". It is properly normalized and makes the most sense.

Perhaps I should provide a note in my original question that the original tables cannot be modified in anyway as hundreds of pages use them.

Comment: It actually doesn't seem normalized at all. Especially if address is duplicated across multiple tables.

Comment: It isnt?? Did you read the tables as they are shown? Absolutely *nothing* is duplicated across tables except the key (familyid).

Comment: @njk: The address is not duplicated. But there are `lastname` and `firstname` columns in both tables. That is not nothing, JM4.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm not sure I conveyed my question well as the "second scenario" answer given is not correct in relation to the 'types' or 'memtype' as suggested. I'll try to do a re-read and refocus tonight. Thanks again.

Comment: I do appreciate the responses here. This is not exactly something I can put into practice as I am the sole DB manager and web developer for this particular firm and updating to the database schema as mentioned would not only require intense DB changes but also changes on thousands of web pages and applications which is not feasible (nor likely possible). I'll use as a guideline for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, it would be more feasible in my opinion to use a more flexible schema like below (simplified):

[image]

The `family` table would assume a household, which contains members from `member`. The relationships between these members would be handled in `member_map`. The `parent_member_id` is optional, in which case would indicate the head of household.

Comment: thanks for your writeup. This is similar to what ypercube wrote and my comment reponse came a bit too late but modifying schema is not possible in this setup. I might consider in future projects if similar activities came about but not sure it really provide any more flexibility but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I entirely understand the question. (because I do not know what the expected result set). 
However, it would be a good idea to separate the family concept from individual members. To do this Family should be a table and family members a separate table called Members. 
(this might be obvious but just for clarity)

create table Family (
  Family_ID,
  Family_Name,
  Family_Address, 
  .
  .
  .
)

create table MEmbers (
  Member_ID
  Is_Primary /*1 or 0*/,
  Member_Name /* expand to as many columns as needed for example - first name, last name ... */, 
  Member_Info /* as Gender, Age ... */
)

Then, your joins should be constructed as: Family join Channels for getting families with some viewing pattern and for individual members as: Family join Channels join Members.

(This is my first comment ever to Stackoverflow. I don't quite know how to syntax highlight ...). Will make it more refined as I find out.

Comment: thanks. As my note states, modifying the schema is not possible. The schema as is has worked well in every other test case with the exception of this single report. I'll consider for future projects but looking to solve current issue.